# "putting" a certain object to the screen from inside an array

Tags: sql, ruby, hashtable

I have an array, "templates".

```
puts templates
```

gives me the following output:

```
{"id"=>4, "subject"=>"invoice", "body"=>"dear sirs", "description"=>"banking", "groups"=>"123", 0=>4, 1=>"invoice", 2=>"dear sirs", 3=>"banking", 4=>"123"}
```

I would like to "put" a certain element e.g. "dear sirs". I have tried:

```
puts templates[2]
```

but this just returns nil. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: That's a _Hash_, not an _Array_, so access its keys via their string names.

Comment: `puts templates[2]` works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access `"dear sirs"` using the key that's associated with it, `"body"`:

```
puts templates["body"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you have hash like this

```
@a = {"id"=>4, "subject"=>"invoice", "body"=>"dear sirs", "description"=>"banking", "groups"=>"123", 0=>4, 1=>"invoice", 2=>"dear sirs", 3=>"banking", 4=>"123"}
```

And if you want to get value of key name 'body', then you can get output like this,

```
puts @a['body'] //Output = dear sirs
puts @a['subject'] //Output = invoice
```

For more information for ruby hash [Ruby Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a hash value by numeric index then you can do `templates.values[index]`

e.g

 `templates.values[0] => 4
 templates.values[1] => "invoice"
 templates.values[2] => "dear sirs"`

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: My answer is based on strong assumptions that may not be true. I have provided steps to validate that.

In-case you are on older ruby version you need to do `puts templates.inspect` in-order to print a `Hash`. Therefore suggesting your variable `templates` is a `String`. Best way to verify:

```
templates.class 
#=> returns Hash or String accordingly.
```

If it return `String`, you can proceed as follows:

Convert the `String` into `Hash`

```
hash = eval(templates)
#=> {"subject"=>"invoice", 0=>4, "description"=>"banking", 1=>"invoice", 2=>"dear sirs", "id"=>4, 3=>"banking", "body"=>"dear sirs", 4=>"123", "groups"=>"123"}
```

Now that its a `Hash` you can access any value using its key like:

```
hash[key]
#=> val
```

Example for your case:

```
hash[2]
#=> "dear sirs"
```